# Exception: Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream - foreach

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, exception

I have a List declared which holds the names of some XML files that are located in the IsolatedStorage for this application. From this, I am trying to pull out the relevant elements of the XML which is then used to create an object that is added to an ObservableCollection to be used for binding on one of the app's pages.

```
private void parseXML()
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            foreach (string xmlname in selectedEventTypes)
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(xmlname, FileMode.Open, isoStore))
                {
                    XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load(isoStream);
                    foreach (XElement xe in xmldoc.Descendants("results"))
                    {
                        Event eventInfo = new Event();
                        eventInfo.eventname = xe.Element("eventname").Value;
                        eventInfo.name = xe.Element("venue").Element("name").Value;
                        eventInfo.address = xe.Element("venue").Element("address").Value;
                        eventInfo.town = xe.Element("venue").Element("town").Value;
                        eventInfo.postcode = xe.Element("venue").Element("postcode").Value;
                        eventInfo.type = xe.Element("venue").Element("type").Value;
                        eventInfo.imageurl = xe.Element("imageurl").Value;
                        eventInfo.date = xe.Element("date").Value;
                        eventInfo.description = xe.Element("description").Value;
                        eventInfo.doorsopen = xe.Element("openingtimes").Element("doorsopen").Value;
                        eventInfo.doorsclose = xe.Element("openingtimes").Element("doorsclose").Value;
                        eventInfo.lastentry = xe.Element("openingtimes").Element("lastentry").Value;
                        eventList.Add(eventInfo);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using a foreach statement in order to iterate through the List and use that as the filename, however I believe this is where the issue lies but do not know how to rectify this.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, `foreach` is unlikely to be relevant here. Which call is throwing the exception? I suspect that at least on of the files doesn't exist.

Comment: The call to this line: `using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(xmlname, FileMode.Open, isoStore))` is what is throwing the exception.

If I replace the foreach line with a simple `string xmlname = "arts.xml";` it works fine, which is what led me to believe that it is the foreach.

Comment: That suggests to me that one of the strings in `selectedEventTypes` is a file which doesn't exist. That's what you should track down.

Comment: Ah damn, that was exactly it. Such a small mistake I'd made. I'd forgotten to add the file extension to one of the strings in the List. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Voting to close as too localized.